# How to find and click on elements that aren't there depending on page size with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation

I am working on a project to automate the process of scheduling my tee time each week. Basically the times open up at 5AM a week ahead so instead of wakng up at 5AM every week I want it to automate the process.

I have run into a problem with selenium. The courses webpage loads easily, and the login is fine, but once I get to the home page I can't click one of the menu buttons. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception Raised Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00527413+2389011]
    Ordinal0 [0x004B9F61+1941345]
    Ordinal0 [0x003AC520+836896]
    Ordinal0 [0x003DA1F3+1024499]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CFF93+982931]
    Ordinal0 [0x003F414C+1130828]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CF974+981364]
    Ordinal0 [0x003F4364+1131364]
    Ordinal0 [0x00404302+1196802]
    Ordinal0 [0x003F3F66+1130342]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CE546+976198]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CF456+980054]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006D9632+1727522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0078BA4D+2457661]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005BEB81+569713]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005BDD76+566118]
    Ordinal0 [0x004C0B2B+1968939]
    Ordinal0 [0x004C5988+1989000]
    Ordinal0 [0x004C5A75+1989237]
    Ordinal0 [0x004CECB1+2026673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x779CFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57A4E+238]
```

I have tried to click this ForeTees button so many different ways and I can't figure it out.

```py
from config.secrets import COURSE_URL
from login import login
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from decorators import base_logger
import time

# Path to Chrome Driver
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r"C:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
FIREFOXDRIVER_PATH = r"C:\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe"


class HomePageDropDown:
    """This class is for locators on the Home Page"""
    DROP_DOWN_MENU = ".ui-link"
    DD_BTN_ATTEMPT_1 = "//a[contains(@href, '#menu']"
    DD_FORETEES_BTN_XPATH = "//span[@class='smartphone-nav-heading'][normalize-space()='Foretees']"
    DD_BUTTON = "//div[@id='mm-menu-link']"


class HomePageLocators:
    """This class is for locators on the members home page after logging in"""
    FORETEES_BUTTON_PARTIAL = "Foretees"
    FORETEES_BUTTON_XPATH = "//span[text()[normalize-space()='Foretees']]"
    FORETEES_XPATH_LONG = "//div[@id='textured-cssmenu']/ul[1]/li[5]/a[1]/span[1]"
    FORETEES_BUTTON_CSS_SELECTOR = "div#textured-cssmenu>ul>li:nth-of-type(5)>a>span"
    FORETEES_BUTTON_PAGE_ID = "//*[@data-pageid='53']"
    # Error Message: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
    FORETEES_BUTTON_XPATH_1 = "//span[@class='textured-nav-heading textured-nav-heading-unselected'][normalize-space()='Foretees']"
    FORETEES_BUTTON_XPATH_2 = "//a/span[contains(@class,'textured-nav-heading textured-nav-heading-unselected')][normalize-space()='Foretees']"


@base_logger()
def click_foretees(driver):
    locator = HomePageLocators.FORETEES_BUTTON_XPATH_2
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator)
        element.click()
        return element

    except exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException as ni:
        print(f"Exception Raised {ni}")

    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException as ne:
        print(f"Exception Raised {ne}")

    except exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException as nv:
        print(f"Exception Raised {nv}")

    except AttributeError as ae:
        print(f"Error Raised {ae}")

@base_logger()
def click_drop_down(driver):
    locator = HomePageDropDown.DD_BUTTON
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator)
        element.click()
        return element
    except exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException as se:
        print(f"Exception Raised {se}")

    except AttributeError as ae:
        print("Element doesn't have that attribute ")


@base_logger()
def home_page(driver):
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, HomePageLocators.DROP_DOWN_MENU).click_and_hold()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    except exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException as se:
        print(se)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a webdriver instance
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)

    # Open the url with driver
    driver.get(COURSE_URL)

    # ================================================================ #
    # RUN INITIAL PROGRAM FUNCTIONS:
    # ================================================================ #

    # run login function
    login(driver)

    # wait for page to load
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # run home_page function
    click_foretees(driver)
    # click_drop_down(driver)
    # ================================================================ #
    # close Browser
    driver.close()
```

I tried to put all the different xpath's and css selectors I tried but I know there are a lot more I am missing.

I would really appreciate any help I can get.